# Can't install programs from ubuntu software centre (17.04)

Tags: software-installation

I'm using ubuntu 17.04 (64 bit). I tried to install a program from ubuntu software centre recently. It showed the status as installing for a few moments and then reverted back to showing the install option. I tried installing other programs but the result is same. I'm new to ubuntu and don't really know how I should proceed.

Comment: can u install from terminal ? `apt-get` or samething ?

Comment: Yes, I've done that. But still can't install anything